# Data Trigger binding another element in different visual tree node

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger, multidatatrigger

How to modify style of one element in a visual tree, based on style in triggers in another element in different visual tree node

For example,I am having a list of colors,

```
        ColorList = new List<ColorViewModel>();
        ColorList.Add(new ColorViewModel() { ColorCode = "#FF0000", ColorName="Red" });
        ColorList.Add(new ColorViewModel() { ColorCode = "#00FF00", ColorName="Green" });
        ColorList.Add(new ColorViewModel() { ColorCode = "#0000FF", ColorName="Blue" });
        this.DataContext = this;
```

I have the colors show in a ItemsControl and their name in another ItemsControl, When I hover on their name, I want to increase the size of color box for the corresponding color.

I tried setting the triggers based on element name, but since the scope is different. The following is the sample code, that covers my complex scenario. Is there a xaml way to overcome this? Any help appreciated.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding ColorCode}">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ColorName, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ColorName" Text="{Binding ColorName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible using XAML only, if `UIElement.IsMouseOver` would have a setter. Since it is read-only it can't be target of a `Binding`. That `IsMouseOver` is read-only makes perfect sense, as it is intended to be set internally solely on mouse input.

Because of this, it is required to either extend `ListBox` (or `ItemsControl`) or to implement an attached behavior.

In order to transport the `IsMouseOver` flag information between both controls, you can add a dedicated property to the data model. The data model (or `DataContext`) is the only link between both item controls.

In the following example, this property is expected to be of the following definition:

```
private bool isPreviewEnabled;
public bool IsPreviewEnabled
{
  get => this.isPreviewEnabled;
  set
  {
    this.isPreviewEnabled = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.IsPreviewEnabled));
  }
}
```

Note that the model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The following example is an attached behavior, that delegates the mouse over flag by providing an attached property as binding target.

**Element.cs**

```
public class Element : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsMouseOver attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverElementProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsMouseOver",
    typeof(bool?),
    typeof(Element),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(bool?), 
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
      OnBindngAttached));

  public static void SetIsMouseOver(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool? value) => attachingElement.SetValue(Element.IsMouseOverProperty, value);

  public static bool? GetIsMouseOver(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(Element.IsMouseOverProperty);

  #endregion

  private static void OnBindngAttached(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Only listen to mouse events when the binding initializes the property.
    // This guarantees single subscription.
    if (d is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && e.OldValue == null)
    {
      frameworkElement.MouseEnter += DelegateIsMouseEnter;
      frameworkElement.MouseLeave += DelegateIsMouseLeave;
    }
  }

  private static void DelegateIsMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    var attachedElement = sender as DependencyObject;
    SetIsMouseOver(attachedElement, true);
  }

  private static void DelegateIsMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    var attachedElement = sender as DependencyObject;
    SetIsMouseOver(attachedElement, false);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ColorCode}">
          <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
              <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
              <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPreviewEnabled}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
                  <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">

        <!-- 
          Delegate the IsMouseOver to the data model, 
          which is the data context of the item container 
        -->
        <Setter Property="Element.IsMouseOver" 
                Value="{Binding IsPreviewEnabled}" />
      </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```